# Why is my JDBC code returning no records when MySQL itself returns 1+ record?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

In an application I've been writing, one of the methods in the DAO layer is supposed to query the database (**MySQL** in this case) returning a list of records that match the criteria.  The table to which it refers is WordInstance and it has 3 foreign keys to 3 other tables(**Words**, **Parts of Speech**, and **Categories**).  The **Category** field in the **wordInstances** table can be **null** but the rest of the fields can not - because a word may not have a category.

I have 2 separate methods **createObjectFromResults** and **createObjectListFromResults**.  Inside createObjectListFromResults, there's a line/loop while(objResults.next()) and inside that calls the other create function to do the work for an individual row.  For whatever reason, it's skipping over that loop as if there's no records to process - except when I take the same statement and plug it into MySQL's workbench, I get 1 row(converting the section of "Category = ?" to "Category is null" for MySQL Workbench) - This is after running it one time and not dropping the schema or table in between executions.  Am I maybe doing something wrong w/ my sQL Query with regard to JDBC for this to return no records?  Code is below:

```
public List<WordInstance> listByWordPartOfSpeechAndCategory(final Word objWord, final PartOfSpeech objPartOfSpeech, final Category objCategory) throws SQLException
{
    if(!isTableExists())
        createTable();

    try
        {
        PreparedStatement objStatement = getConnection().prepareStatement("select " + getQueriedColumnsForSelect() + " from " + TableName + " where Word = ? and PartOfSpeech = ? and Category = ?;");

        objStatement.setInt(1, objWord.getId());
        objStatement.setInt(2, objPartOfSpeech.getId());

        if(objCategory != null)
            objStatement.setInt(3, objCategory.getId());
        else
            objStatement.setNull(3, Types.INTEGER);

        return(createObjectListFromResults(objStatement.executeQuery()));
        }
    catch(SQLException objException)
        {
        msObjLogger.error("There was a problem retrieving the word instances that had the same word, part of speech, and category...", objException);

        return(null);
        }
    finally
        {
        closeConnection();
        }
}
```

TableName for this DAO object is "WordInstances" and getQueriedColumnsForSelect is:

```
protected String getQueriedColumnsForSelect()
{
    return("Id, Word, PartOfSpeech, Category, Definition, Slang");
}
```

createObjectListFromResults is here:

```
protected List<WordInstance> createObjectListFromResults(final ResultSet objResults) throws SQLException
{
    List<WordInstance> lstWordInstances = new ArrayList<WordInstance>();

    while(objResults.next())
        lstWordInstances.add(createObjectFromResults(objResults));

    return(lstWordInstances);
}
```

I can include any other code as requested to help figure this problem out.  Like I said - in MySQL itself it returns a row (or more as I noticed the problem because there were multiple records in there) - Actually the multiple records confound me because I have a unique key for Word, PartOfSpeech and Category unless the fact that Category is null makes it un-unique-able.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Show us the code for `createObjectFromResults()`.  In any case, i don't recommend chaining methods and passing around a `ResultSet` like this.

Comment: I found (and just posted) the answer - I use a 2nd method passing the resultset to the 2nd method because I find code reuse a worse sin than blasphemy on the bible is to a devout Catholic.  The createObjectFromResults is actually causing me another problem now but I'll figure that out and I think I did - if I'm wrong and it's more difficult, I'll be back to post another question of course

Comment: How would a devout Protestant react to your comment?

Comment: I don't care how they would or would not because this is not a religious concept but just saying that code reuse is the worst of the worse crimes in programming.

Answer (score -1):

The solution I found on another site and adapted to my code was to compose the SQL string based on if the Category passed in was null then use " and Category is null" else " and Category = ?" and when setting parameters then, just set Category if it's not null - if it is null then the sQL statement is taken care of w/ a hard coded "is null" - I wish JDBC allowed to use null in place of a ? like a parameter but it's only really an option with update statements setting fields, not in the where clause.

Comment: That has nothing to do with JDBC. Null is perfectly allowed for a parameter, but in standard SQL, comparisons with `null` using `=` results in unknown (which is interpreted as false). If you have different results in your query tool when using literally `category = null`, then your query tool is using a different null-handling setting for its session.